# RK4 - Runge-Kutta Algorithm for ODEs of a single variable

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods, differential-equations

Sorry in advance if this is a simple/stupid question.

Every explanation of RK4 that I've seen uses a function of two variables; eg. f' = f(u, t) with initial conditions  t<sub>0</sub>  and  u<sub>0</sub>=u(t<sub>0</sub>) and a step value of Δt.

Which results in the following method of approximation:

k<sub>1</sub> = Δt * f'(t<sub>n</sub>,y<sub>n</sub>)

k<sub>2</sub> = Δt * f'(t<sub>n</sub> + (1/2) *Δt, y<sub>n</sub> + (1/2) * k<sub>1</sub>)

k<sub>3</sub> = Δt * f'(t<sub>n</sub> + (1/2) *Δt, y<sub>n</sub> + (1/2) * k<sub>2</sub>)

k<sub>4</sub> = Δt * f'(t<sub>n</sub> + Δt,y<sub>n</sub> + k<sub>3</sub>)

yielding:

u<sub>n+1</sub> = u<sub>n</sub> + (1/6)*(k<sub>1</sub> + 2*k<sub>2</sub> + 2* k<sub>3</sub> + k<sub>4</sub>)

t<sub>n+1</sub> = t<sub>n</sub> + Δt

How does a single variable function eg. u' = u(t) with initial conditions t<sub>0</sub>  and  u<sub>0</sub>=u(t<sub>0</sub>) and a step value of Δt change the implementation of the method?

Comment: The function should be **f'=f(t,u)** (time is the first variable)

Comment: @Aziz this is but a convention. Everybody understands they way it's written here.

Comment: Your function just has no explicit dependence on t. So, it is just the same as you already wrote, simply replace t by 0.

Comment: @jojo No, I'm not referring to the convention. The question has f(u,t) in the top but uses f(t,u) in the RK4 equations. I'm sure it's a typo but it has to be clarified.

Comment: @Aziz fair enough, this is indeed an inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation need not change at all. Your function is simply *f*(*t*, *u*) = 2 *u* - 1 (that is, there's no explicit dependency on *t* in *f*; only an implicit one because *u* is itself a function of *t*). Just apply the method and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your ODE

[image: ODE]

is not explicitly a function of time `t`. Therefore, in the RK4 equations, you have:

[image: RK4]

which, after substituting `u'`, will be:

[image: RK4_2]

Then you can simply compute u<sub>n+1</sub>.